# Sanitize a custom date meta field

Tags: sanitization

I have to sanitize the following

```
<input type="date" id="periodo_1da" name="periodo_1da" class="list_prezzi" ><?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'periodo_1da', $user->ID ) ); ?>
```

I tryed with

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'prezzi_1da', sanitize_meta( $_POST['prezzi_1da'] ) );
```

but also with sanitize_text_field and sanitize_textarea, nothing works, which is the correct method?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're missing the `value=""`, it seems like you use `<input>` as a regular HTML tag, and not a self-closing one.

A basic example of what it should be like if I only use your value and ignore all the other attributes.

```php
<input value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'periodo_1da', $user->ID ) ); ?>">
```

And here is the input tag with all the attributes and the correct value attribute.

```php
<input type="date" id="periodo_1da" name="periodo_1da" class="list_prezzi" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'periodo_1da', $user->ID ) ); ?>">
```